# Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

as stated in the title I get the following error:
Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource.

Specifically in the console of Microsoft edge:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'info'

angular-resource.js (444,1)

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Review
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20Review
at Anonymous function (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4630:13)
at getService (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4783:11)
at Anonymous function (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4635:13)
at getService (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4783:11)
at injectionArgs (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4807:9)
at invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4834:7)
at enforcedReturnValue (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4676:7)
at invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4842:9)
at Anonymous function (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4636:13)
at getService (https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js:4783:11) <div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
angular.js (14328,11)
```

I googled the error and came across multiple solutions, but it seems I'm still doing something wrong, even while trying implementing said solutions...

index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="VideogameReviewsApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

for simplicity I have included all the code in app.js:

```
'use strict';

var VideogameReviewsApp = angular.module('VideogameReviewsApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']).
     config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: ReviewCtrl, templateUrl: 'review.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
     }]);

VideogameReviewsApp.factory('Review', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost/videogamereviews/review/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

var ReviewCtrl = function ($scope,Review) {
    alert("mop")
    $scope.items = Review.get();
};
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Ashley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your angular-resource reference to match the angular version.

```
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-resource.js">
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('VideogameReviewsApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])
.controller("testctrl",function($scope){
$scope.appname = "resourceTest";
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="VideogameReviewsApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testctrl">     

{{appname}}
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-resource.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I should ask a new question, but its kind of a followup:
I have a REST api in spring. If I directly access it through url http://localhost/videogamereviews/review is being accessed. Any 
"http://localhost/videogamereviews/review/" I get my data as expected.

However when I try it  with angular through the browser I get a 404
response. This is strange because in the header I can see suggestions?

Comment: sorry, I messed up, this is what I meant:

Maybe I should ask a new question, but its kind of a followup:
I have a REST api in spring. If I directly access it through url 
"http://localhost/videogamereviews/review/", I get my data as expected.

However when I try it  with angular through the browser I get a 404
response. This is strange because in the header I can see http://localhost/videogamereviews/review is being accessed. Any suggestions?